# SQL Full Text Query - behaving differently depending on how I call a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, full-text-search

I've come across a confusing issue.

I have a Stored Procedure in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database which takes a single parameter `@Query` and runs a simple Full Text Search query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchMyTable
    @Query varchar(250)
AS
    SELECT
        ...
    FROM
        ...
        INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE (t, *, @Query) ft ON ( t.Id = ft.[Key] )
ORDER BY
    ft.Rank DESC
```

When I open a query window in SQL Server Management Studio, and test this by typing:

```
SearchMyTable 'truck'
```

It works great.

When I type the following, it still works, and returns the same results (presumably ignoring the noise word '**a**')

```
SearchMyTable 'a truck'
```

But then I took into an ASP.NET page.

```
private SqlDataReader DoQuery(SqlConnection connection, string query) {
    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("Query", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    parameter.Value = query;

    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "SearchMyTable";
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    return command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

When I call `DoQuery(connection, "truck");` it works, and gets the same results again, which I format and print out on my page.

**But when I do the second version with the noise word, `DoQuery(connection, "a truck");`, the SqlDataReader comes back empty with no rows!**

I'm very confused. I assume that my stored procedure is fine, as it works when calling it directly from a query window in SQL Management Studio.

So why does it seem to get different results depending on whether I call it as a raw query, or through the SQL Server ADO.NET provider in my ASP.NET page? Am I missing something?

**EDIT: It would seem there is nothing wrong with the above. I found a solution, which may even be a bug in SQL/.NET. See my answer below.**

Comment: I'm surprised that C# works at all because you've left out the `@` at the start of the parameter name. I thought it was compulsory.

Comment: Tim: No, the "@" is not compulsory. Ross: have you looked at the generated T-SQL using SQL Profiler?

Comment: Rick - I'm using SQL Express so profiler is not included. Will try profiling it some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

The code I didn't show you was how I read my data reader in my ASP.NET page:

```
if (dr.HasRows) {
    ...
    while (dr.Read()) { ... }
    ...
} else {
    // no results
    ...
}
```

It turned out that `dr.HasRows` was returning `false`, even though there were rows! This has never happened to me before in 10 years of ADO.NET experience.

So I changed it to:

```
if (dr.Read()) {
    ...
    do { ... } while (dr.Read());
    ...
} else {
    // no results
    ...
}
```

And it works.

Comment: juts out of interest do you have NOCOUNT SET OFF in the database. Could that account for this odd behaviour?

Comment: Exactly the same problem described here - sounds like it's down to messages thrown back from sql

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483787/is-there-a-bug-in-sqldatareader-hasrows-when-running-against-sql-server-2008

Comment: Neiff - that is the exact issue! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try running SQL Server Profiler to see what SQL is actually executing when run from the code.

Comment: I'm using SQL Express so profiler is not included. But on your hunch I'll do a few more tests.