# .HasRows() function on data reader taking forever

Tags: vb.net, odbcdatareader

I have some simple code, an `if` statement checking the `HasRows` of a data reader and for some reason when I run my code in Visual Studio 2017 it takes forever to evaluate and return the answer (while writing this, my code has been running for 4 minutes). Any suggestions?

```
 Dim cmd As OdbcCommand
 Dim rdr As OdbcDataReader

cmd = New OdbcCommand("select GLPN,GLFY,GLDCT,GLDOC,GLCO,GLDGJ,GLANI,GLSBL,GLLT,GLCRCD,GLAA,GLU,GLGLC,GLEXA,GLICUT,GLR2,GLR1,GLSFX,GLOKCO" _
                      & ",GLEXR,GLODOC,GLPKCO,GLPDCT,GLCN,GLDKJ,GLVINV,GLIVD,GLPO,GLDCTO,GLLNID,GLTORG,GLAN8,GLICU,GLOPSQ,GLJBCD" _
                      & ",GLACR,GLABR2,GLABR1,GLDGJ,GLLT,GLCRCD,GLEXA,GLICUT,GLEXR,GLDKJ,GLIVD,GLAN8,GLICU,GLACR,GLKCO,GLSBLT,GLOBJ,GLSUB,GLJELN,GLEXTL,GLCRR,GLBCRC" _
                      & " from " _
                      & "PRODDTA.F0911 where GLPOST = 'P' and GLDGJ >= ? and GLDGJ <= ? and (GLLT = 'AA' or GLLT = 'CA') and GLDOC = 206940", cnn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("?GLUPMJs", OdbcType.Int).Value = todaysdate - 14
cmd.Parameters.Add("?GLUPMJe", OdbcType.Int).Value = todaysdate
cnn.Open()
cmd.CommandTimeout = 300
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader

If rdr.HasRows() Then

    'Do a bunch of stuff

End if
```

Edit1: Still getting the funny issue but it I have noticed it's only in one spot, I have the "HasRows()" Check in multiple spots and it is working fast 3ms and such. it's only on the one query.

Edit2: The query I referenced above runs on SQL developer very fast total of 1.202 seconds last time I tried, it also returns no messages.

Edit3: I am wondering if it has something to do with the amount of fields I am returning, the other queries that run fast on this line are returning much smaller field counts.

Comment: Depending on the data inside your table, you could maybe speed up your query when you change the sequence of your `WHERE`-clause. Probably like this: `where GLPOST = 'P' and GLDOC = 206940 and (GLLT = 'AA' or GLLT = 'CA') and GLDGJ >= ? and GLDGJ <= ?`

Comment: These columns names in JDE database are frightening. They look somehow worse than Dynamics GP.

Comment: Sorry to be specific, my Query runs fast, the rdr = CMD.ExecuteReader runs in a few seconds.  when it gets to the line "If rdr.HasRows() Then"  where it hangs up.  the specific run took 517 seconds, previous run took similar times.  I would expect this line of code should be returning in less then a second.

Comment: The ExecuteReader probably didn't actually execute the query.  It defers the execution until it's needed.  HasRows has to execute it.  What is your back-end database and how big is the table?  Are there good indexes on the fields in the query?  If not, it'll do a table scan which is slow.

Comment: well maybe, when I run the query above in a SQL developer it returns my rows in 1.05 seconds  so I don't think it's the query

Comment: @dwilliss your comment is the correct answer.  I put a test code ahead of my hasRows() "If rdr.read() then stop" Ran the code again and this time this line of code took the time to process and when the code got to the rdr.HasRows() it went by very fast.  I find it interesting though that the query returns in 1 second via SQL developer but takes several minutes via the code.  I suspect it may be the ODBC part.

Comment: I think you should probably post the right answer as an answer and mark it as solved so it is clear to anyone that might find this question useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the delay on HasRows() is because the ExecuteReader didn't actually execute the query, it Defers the execution until it's needed.  HasRows is the one executing it.  thanks to Dwillis for pointing it out.

I tested this by putting a line of code ahead of it and this is where the delay sat and when hasRows ran it was fast.

Interestingly the same sql run in Sql Management Studio runes in 1.5 seconds returning all rows, yet in the Code it takes for ever which is a different issue but also may be due to ODBC settings.

Answer (score 1):

This may not speed it up any but have you tried??

```
While rdr.Read()
'Do a bunch of stuff
End While
```

EDIT:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
dt.Load(rdr)
If dt.Rows.Count >= 0 Then
   'Do a bunch of stuff
End If
```

Comment: Not yet, I'll see if it makes a difference

Comment: It behaved the same as the HasRows(). I am going to edit my post further with more details.

Comment: Try throwing the reader into a datatable and checking its rows.count?? I am just guessing here,  I'll post example in edit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that the query is taking a lot to be executed. If you are only interested in checking the existence of records you could perform a query with "`SELECT TOP 1 1`" and use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: the query it's self seems to be fine, it finishes loading the reader in a few seconds.  it seems to hang up on the checking if my reader then has rows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not the only one having trouble with the `HasRows` method. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483787/is-there-a-bug-in-sqldatareader-hasrows-when-running-against-sql-server-2008) post, the OP stated a problem with that method, although it is SQL-SERVER. But I think the solution might be useful, since both DataReaders inherit from the same class and they are closely related.

If you read the post that they reference in the question and the most voted answer, you'll see that they concluded that `HasRows` showed a buggy behavior when **the SQL query execution returned not only some data results, but also a message**. They ended up using an alternative way to check if there were any data on the data reader based on the `Read()` method, which proved to be more reliable.

In their case, the problem was that  `HasRows` property was set to false when the reader actually contained data, but maybe it is related to your performance problem. You should definitely give a try to the `Read` method just to be sure that your query is not the problem.

P.S: another interesting [link](https://andydote.co.uk/2012/10/30/sqldatareaderhasrows-problems/) with a person reporting the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, I had read the last interesting link you provided before posting this I ran the query in SQL developer and I don't see any messages similar to SQL management studio, but that could just be a quirk of SQL Developer.

Comment: `OdbcDataReader` and `SqlDataReader` both inherit from `DbDataReader`, and the implementation of `HasRows` is as a matter of fact in the base class (`DbDataReader`). So my guess is that any issues with this method affect all the classes that inherit from `DbDataReader`. That is why I say that the issues might be related.