# SqlDataAdapter and SqlDataReader

Tags: c#

I have a stored procedure which returns a certain number of rows.

Case 1: When I use SqlDataAdapter

```
SqlDataAdapter sdAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
ds = new DataSet();
sdAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
sdAdapter.Fill(ds);
int recordCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

Case 2: When I use SqlDataReader

```
SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
   while (reader.Read())
    {
     recordCount++;
    }
 }
```

In Case 1, the recordCount is 15 which is correct.

In Case 2, for some reason, reader.HasRows is returning false.

Am I doing anything wrong in terms of syntax? I am confident that myCommand has been built properly since I do get the count in Case 1.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: can you perhaps show the sql command that you are using..

Comment: impossible to say from the code you posted...

Comment: Hi, if I comment the reader.HasRows in Case 2, I am still able to perform reader.Read() and get the value of recordCount. So just wondering is it is possible that hasRows return false but there is still reader pointing to the contents of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (reader.HasRows)` is redundant. When you say `while (reader.Read())`, it will only loop if there are any rows. Also, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197220/sqldatareader-hasrows-returns-false-since-sql-2008-upgrade) will explain that HasRows requires a scrollable cursor. Read about the cursors [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172375.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

1.A DataReader works in a connected environment,
               whereas DataSet works in a disconnected environment.
               2.A DataSet represents an in-memory cache of data consisting of any number of inter related            DataTable objects. A DataTable object represents a tabular block of in-memory data.

more detail go to [sqldataadapter or sqldatareader](http://deepakgoelblog.blogspot.de/2012/06/difference-between-sqldataadapter-or.html)